# Is $\omega + \omega^2 = \omega^2$ true?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Just a simple question. Is $\omega + \omega^2$ equal to $\omega^2$, I’ve just been thinking about it and if that’s false and it equals $\omega^2+\omega$ then we could define a set of countable ordinals using Cantor’s diagonal argument with cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ which would prove the continuum hypothesis, I think, which means that because the continuum hypothesis is unsolvable under ZFC that $\omega + \omega^2$ must just equal $\omega^2$. Unless I’ve done something wrong (which is likely), which is why I’m asking the question.

Comment: There *are* uncountably many countable ordinals. How does that prove the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: I meant $2^{\aleph_0}$ countable ordinals. I’ll edit that.

Comment: How? Cantor's diagonal doesn't prove that $\Bbb R$ or $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have size $2^{\aleph_0}$, it just proves they are uncountable. If you can sketch me your argument in the comments, that would be interesting.

Comment: You’re right (of course), but it does prove that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$. And the powerset of the naturals has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ so we could see that my (edited) argument holds. Although this is beginning to get irrelevant as my statement of $\omega + \omega^2 = \omega^2$ is true as shown in Stella Biderman’s answer.

Comment: No. It really doesn't. That requires a whole other argument. The diagonal argument, if nothing else, proves that $2^{\aleph_0}\neq\aleph_0$.

Comment: Oh, it’s the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem that can prove that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N) = \Bbb R$. Okay, my reasoning was false but my statement was correct (within a false universe). Also, I never mentioned any needed use for $\Bbb R$... I just needed $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: $\aleph_1$ never shows up in your argument, so I don’t see how it could possibly prove the CH.

Comment: I still don’t see how this pertains to my question. If $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals ($\omega_1$), and you have a subset of $\omega_1$ that has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, then the cardinality of $\omega_1$ must be greater than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$, and seeing as $\aleph_1$ is the smallest cardinal after $\aleph_0$ they must be equal as there is no cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\aleph_0\lt\kappa\lt\aleph_1$.

Comment: Yes, but we are all curious as to *how* you'd deduce there is a subset of size $2^{\aleph_0}$. You keep claiming "Cantor's diagonal argument". But that's not right. The diagonal argument is only enough to prove that the set of countable ordinals (or the subset of those that you defined) is uncountable. Why is it specifically of size $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: If you have a subset of the natural numbers, you can take the first element (call it e1) and change its value (call it e1’) and repeat to get a new set of {e1’, e2’, e3’...} we can do the same with an with sums of ordinals, for example, (assuming the equation $\omega + \omega^2 = \omega^2 + \omega$): {$2\omega + 5\omega^2 + \omega^3 + 4\omega^4\cdots$}, we could change the coefficients of the term she and create a subset with different coefficients. This uses Cantor’s diagonal argument to create a subset in the same way, with the same uncountable number of element S as $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think what L. McDonald is trying to say is: if $$\sum_{i\in\omega}a_i\omega^i=\sum_{i\in\omega}b_i\omega^i\iff \forall i(a_i=b_i)$$ then CH follows. This is true of course, but the hypothesis is wildly false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addition of ordinals is non-commutative. Additive elements can “combine together” to equal the largest in the sum. In general, elements combine when the one on the left is smaller than the one on the right. So $\omega^2 = \omega + \omega^2 = \omega^2\neq \omega^2 + \omega$. This is covered on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) with diagrams showing why it comes out this way.

Note that at least one element has to be infinite for it to combine. It’s still the case that $3+5=8=5+3$. Finite and infinite numbers combine, so $3+\omega=\omega\neq\omega+3$

Comment: That’s what I thought, I just had to check...